# Attaching calendar icon to gmail sidebar

Tags: php, gmail, icalendar

I want to send mail to clients with two information, one is event for calendar and other is location. This picture is showing example of that:

https://skitch.com/kkatusic/gjyrh/appointment-not-confirmed-yet.png-50-documents-50-total-pages

my question is how to set up this in mail function that is build with php?

Thx.

Comment: Why have you added the **gmail** tag ? where is that relevant ?

Comment: Because that email would be opening in gmail accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized how to manage it. Trick base in "subject" of your email and "body".

When your subject has: Your appointment @ Thursday December 29, 2011 at 10:00am you will see calendar icon in right sidebar.

If you in "body" of email message attach lines like: when:, where:, start: end:, with:; all this data would be attached to the calendar when you click on calendar icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create iCal event using this library -> http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php

I have not used MicroMaps - but i would imagine thats just a URL ?

As for adding them to the "sidebar" of an email - that will require some HTML formatting within the email to make the "sidebar" appear on the right ...